# Firebase, leave my debugger console

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

Since updating to the latest version of `Firebase`. There are several messages in `Xcode`'s console that just should not be there, such as:

> 2016-06-27 14:39:59.331 appName[9174:932231] Configuring the default app.

or

> 2016-06-27 14:39:59.444 appName[9174:]  Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
>   )

and so on.

I usually try to keep my console clean for debugging and for other issues, that can be solved.

Is it possible to suppress all default messages from Firebase and if so, how?

**Edit**

As to `Firebase 3.8.0` the messages are even longer, lots of stuff I don't mind about at the moment.

I have tried to set the line below in `info.plist` to , it didn't help much

```
FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not yet possible to fully disable the Firebase info messages. The Firebase components are currently at different stages of an implementation.